# Xcode 15 Beta Issue using simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode15

I hope someoe can help me to solve this issue. I encountered this error upon update to xcode 15. When I uncheck the debug executable on edit scheme my app stuck on launch screen. Advance thank you

`attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.)`

I expect to run my application using simulator while using xcode 15

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the eror message?